# Java Arrays and external files

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble beginning this program that I was given by my professor. Here is the prompt and sample output:

Read 20 pairs of numbers (ID number and score respectively) into two separate arrays.  Find the average score.  Print a table as shown below of the ID, score and difference (score - average) for each student, one student per line.  Print the sum, average, and count of score at the head of the table as shown.  Round the average and difference to 2 decimal places.

Output:

```
End of reading from file. 
Sum     =   4853 
Average = 242.65 Count   =   20 


Id        Score     Diff 

115   257     14.35

123       253     10.35 

116   246     3.35 

113   243     0.35 

112   239    -3.65 

104   239    -3.65

110   238    -4.65 

218   243     0.35 

208   242    -0.65 

222   223    -19.65 

223       230    -12.65 

213   229    -13.65 

207   228    -14.65 

203   224    -18.65 

305   265     22.35 

306   262     19.35 

311   256     13.35 

325   246     3.35 

321   245     2.35 

323   245     2.35
```

My main problem right now is figuring out how to sort the ID and Scores into two separate Arrays. I read the files by using

```
Scanner kbReader = new File("C:\\\Users\\\Guest\\\Documents\\\java programs\\\Prog590b\\\Prog590b.in");
```

But I can't find a way to sort them into the arrays. I'm not asking anyone to write my entire code, but to help me figure out how to sort them into the arrays like the prompt asks. Could someone provide some guidance/feedback on how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your non working code

Comment: Why do professors always insist on doing it the hard way?...I suppose there's a valuable lesson in there somewhere.

Comment: provide your Prog590b.in file structure

Answer (score 0):

Start with reading the IDs and scores line by line and putting them in two separate lists (one for ID, one for score). When you have achieved that, the rest should by obvious.

Comment: If it was so obvious to the OP i doubt they would be posting this question... maybe you could elaborate

Comment: I guess it is not too much to ask for searching a possibility to read in files line by line.

Comment: I don't read something like this: "Read 20 pairs of numbers (ID number and score respectively) into two separate arrays. Find the average score. Print a table as shown below of the ID, score and difference (score - average) for each student, one student per line. Print the sum, average, and count of score at the head of the table as shown. Round the average and difference to 2 decimal places."

Answer (score 0):

**Inserting values in Arrays**

I would suggest you first take the first few digits (ID), assuming all of them have the same number of digits, to be placed in an array.
This should be quite easy: just use the *substring* function in the string class.

Now for the score you should keep going along the line untill you find a space after the score. And then take the substring of that; from the starting index to the final index(you will have to keep a count for this)

**Sorting the Arrays**

There are many ways to sort arrays, lists, linked lists and so on. 
I would suggest you search online for algorithms and try to trace through the code to understand what each line of the code means and how it sorts your array An if statement should work here:

If you do not care much about efficiency I would suggest you look at selection sort or insertion sort! Once you underatand how the algorithms work you can sort depending on ID or score quite easily! :)

Selection Sort: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Hope that helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

First off your scanner is declared wrong.
you need to do something like this

```
Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Guest\\Documents\\java programs\\Prog590b\\Prog590b.in"));
```

Next if the file is ID Score {newline} and so on

You need to use the split function.

```
while(kbReader.hasNext()){
    String line = kbReader.nextLine();
    String splitLine = line.split(" ");

    ArrayID.add(splitLine[0]);
    ArrayScore.add(splitLine[1]);
}
```